# How do I solve $A_{n+2}-3A_{n+1}+A_{n}=n$ with $A_{0}=A_{1}=1$ using method of generating function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

$A_{n+2}-3A_{n+1}+A_{n}=n$ with $A_{0}=A_{1}=1$ using method of generating function

I deducted the following formula: 
$$ 
F(x)= \frac{x^3}{(x-1)(2x-1)}-\frac{1}{x-1} \;,
$$ where $F(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n  x^n$, from here I don't know how to continue.

Comment: I think you have to decompose as partial fractions and then regrouping in order to read the general $a_n$.

Comment: Divide through by $x^2$ first on both sides though or you cannot do partial fractions with the first term on the right. You can multiply back with $x^2$ when you are finished.

Comment: check the generating function should be $-\frac{1}{(-1+x)^2}-\frac{2}{-1+x}+\frac{x}{1-3 x+x^2}$

Comment: Are you set on using generating functions? It would be easier with the characteristic polynomial.